# How to get Leaflet Marker-Cluster Freezable methods show up in VS Code IntelliSense

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I am working on an Angular project where I use Leaflet map service. I came across a problem of clustering. I wanted to toggle clustering and to do so I found a package which has methods that enable/disable clustering feature: [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable#leafletmarkerclusterfreezable)

I have followed the instructions for package installation:

- `npm install leaflet.markercluster.freezable --save`
  which installed it under my `node_modules` folder and it updated `package.json`(Installation Successfull)
- now if I try to `import 'leaflet.markercluster.freezable';` in my **Type-Script File** my VS Code does not show the methods from the package in the IntelliSense feature.

I don't understand what had gone wrong (I think there might be problem with import).

Comment: The package doesn't have typings, does it?

Comment: There is no typings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no typings available yet for Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable library.

You should be able to write them yourself, something in the lines of:

**leaflet.markercluster.freezable.d.ts**

```ts
import 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster';

declare module 'leaflet' {
  // Augment the MCG class through an interface with the same name
  interface MarkerClusterGroup {
    freezeAtZoom(frozenZoom?: number | boolean | 'max' | 'maxKeepSpiderfy'): this;

    unfreeze(): this;

    disableClustering(): this;

    disableClusteringKeepSpiderfy(): this;

    enableClustering(): this;
  }
}
```

Then reference this definition file in your TypeScript project configuration.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAGTgMyhEcBEAbApgQ2TxkwG4AoUSWLPQ4gOhHygGtcoBjbAVwGcYHMuXIATXNxa44ICKJ544AcjpFcMJXADe5OHGAA7QVGT5O0gLIt2UAMK8BHAOJoeYbbr0oouXAC9cAEEYAC0IdAAKVAgAgzD0AH4ALjgDHhAAIw44AB84DPC6A1zlZgAPTTylcoBpXzAAZTBgcRMATyUAShSYAAtgPgpPPR4DVF8AiO64PoGhrzhRAfwMvHt+Y0MAcyme-sGRBaW+FbWHTYMtutxG5tbkNt2Z-fmvXANT3HXHKG2n2YOegAvuQQeROBADAIZJwtnAALyIJjWDjfYwuCBuKYUECwhijcb+XDY8gAelJegAeglyEA)

Comment: "Then reference this definition file in your TypeScript project configuration.". How.?

Comment: Probably either list it in the `"files"` array of [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), or simply within one of your app files: `import './leaflet.markercluster.freezable.d.ts'`

Comment: I created "leaflet.markercluster.freezable.d.ts" under "src" folder and imported it in one of my "ts" file like this "import '../../../leaflet.markercluster.freezable.d.ts';", but VS code did not show any suggestions, I've tried refreshing/ restarting VS code.

Comment: Sorry I do not use VS code. You should probably ask a separate question for this different step of using a local definition file. I assume there should already be plenty resources on this topic. With WebStorm, merely adding this `.d.ts` file in the project folder makes it include the new methods in its Code Completion feature.

Comment: That actually worked after you made the edit.!. I've been referring to this problem since two weeks. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Seems like VS code IntelliSense is stricter than WebStorm code completion then… not sure which one is more compliant to TypeScript spec though. I am glad this version works with both.

Answer (score 0):

Please add leaflet.markercluster.freezable.js file path into your angular cli json file in script section like below

```
..\node_modules\leaflet.markercluster.freezable\dist\leaflet.markercluster.freezable.js

"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.min.js",
   "../node_modules/leaflet.markercluster.freezable/dist/leaflet.markercluster.freezable.js"
      ],
```

Then I think it will working
import 'leaflet.markercluster.freezable'

Comment: That didn't work.!, I have lots(>500) of packages installed(bootstrap, jQuery etc) where I didn't place anything in the Scripts array(its empty) but all those packages still work.